# How to implement the Google Analytics event monitoring on a website if the standard Analytics tracking code seems not to be enough?

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

The website [www.3dz.it](https://www.3dz.it/) is using with WordPress.

There are four languages and each one on a different domain (Italian .it, France .fr, etc.). It is in this way using WPML with the multi-domain option, since April 2018.

Up to April 2018, the events monitoring was going. For three months with the four domains, we were without data; in July we add the new analytics code so each language has an own Analytics property.
But we are still without the monitoring of the events.

Google analytics tracking code is since July 2018 set how is actually online.

```html
<?php if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en'){?>
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-77106642-4"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-77106642-4');
</script>
<?php } elseif(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='it'){?>
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-77106642-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-77106642-1');
</script>
<?php } elseif(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='es'){?>
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-77106642-3"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-77106642-3');
</script>
<?php } elseif(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='fr'){?>
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-77106642-5"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-77106642-5');
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

**Someone can tell me please how to implement the code to obtain the monitoring of the events again?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the different library of Analytics. I solved it calling google assistance. I changed the event script in the website and I modified the conversion in Analytics (event categories and actions)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to add the tracking codes on the website using Google Tag Manager? It's very easy to add multiple tracking codes into your Google Tag Manager account and only place one GTM-code to your website.

Comment: Thank you. I also just thought to proceed for this way. But I never used it before.

Answer (score 0):

[The developer notes](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events) are pretty straightforward with regarding adding event tracking to the page, for the gtag version of GA. However, I would also agree that managing your GA set-up and event tracking via Google Tag Manager would be more appropriate and scalable for your situation.

Comment: Thank you. I also just thought to proceed for this way. But I never used it before.